# Error when downloaded zip files from Google Storage bucket

Tags: java, servlets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, zip

I have a web page on App Engine with Java servlets. This page connects with Google's storage buckets for retrieve zip files. But when they are downloaded, and I try open them, show me a `"truncated zip file header"` error. And I don't know what it means.

Before in the servlet, I stored all content give for the bucket into a byte array, and then converted it to String because the file was in JSON format. But I tried to do this with the zip file, and I got the above error. I know that the files is fine, so not is that files is broken. I am also using the correct mime type: `"application/zip"` (I think). So i don't know what can be.

This is basically my code that I use to get files from bucket:

```
public byte[] getFile(String path) {
   this.storege = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).build().getService();

   this.blob = storege.get(BlobId.of(PROJECT_URL, path));

   byte[] bs = blob.getContent(Blob.BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());

   return bs;
}
```

And, when I worked with JSON files, only convert `byte[]` into `String`.

How can I download the files correctly ?

In advance, thank you very much, and excuse my English.

Comment: Can you show whole error stack? and did you tried on one zip file or it's for every zip file?

Comment: @vitooh yes, in all zip files it give me error.
Only that the error not is the same. Sometimes it show me: "warning [image.zip]:  474 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile (attempting to process anyway) error [image.zip]:  start of central directory not found; zipfile corrupt."
That's show with the test file.
And other times, when i try with my files, it shows me: "caution:  zipfile comment truncated. Error [PAA.zip]:  missing 4248027426 bytes in zipfile (attempting to process anyway)
error [PAA.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile"